# Postgresql how to combine these two queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to combine these two queries, but I can't figure out how

```
SELECT id FROM comments WHERE thread_id = $1 AND parent_id is NULL
```

This returns a integer. i.e - 5

And then use the id result (5) for this recursive query

```
With RECURSIVE recursetree AS
(
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_id = (use the id 5 here)
 UNION
 SELECT t.*
 From comments t
 JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.comment_id = t.parent_id                         
 )
 SELECT * from recursetree
```

Comment: You should post current data and desired result.

Comment: Select id simply returns an integer, say 5 and I want to use that 5 in the recursive query

Comment: Did you try `With RECURSIVE recursetree AS ( SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_id = (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE thread_id = $1 AND parent_id is NULL) UNION SELECT t.*
 From comments t JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.comment_id = t.parent_id ) SELECT * from recursetree` ?

Comment: I think i'm going just going to keep it as two queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put the first query into the anchor of the recursive subquery:

```
With RECURSIVE recursetree AS (
      SELECT c.
      FROM comments c
      WHERE thread_id = $1 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT c.*
      FROM comments c JOIN
           recursetree
           rt ON rt.comment_id = c.parent_id                         
     )
SELECT * 
FROM recursetree;
```

Also note:

- `UNION ALL` makes more sense than `UNION`, unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- The table alias `c` makes more sense for `comments` than the arbitrary letter `t`.
- The `$1` suggests that you are munging the query string with a parameter.  You should be using parameters for the query.